# Comparing signed 64 bit number using 32 bit bitwise operations in Lua

Tags: lua, redis

I am using Lua on Redis and want to compare two signed 64-bit numbers, which are stored in two 8-byte/character strings.

How can I compare them using the libraries available in Redis?
 http://redis.io/commands/EVAL#available-libraries

I'd like to know `>/<` and `==` checks.  I think this probably involves pulling two 32-bit numbers for each 64-bit int, and doing some clever math on those, but I am not sure.

I have some code to make this less abstract.  `a0`, `a1`, `b0`, `b1` are all 32 bit numbers used to represent the msb & lsb's of two 64-bit signed int 64s:

```
-- ...
local comp_int64s = function (a0, a1, b0, b1)
    local cmpres = 0
    -- TOOD: Real comparison
    return cmpres
end
local l, a0, a1, b0, b1
a0, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack("I4", ARGV[1]))
a1, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack("I4", ARGV[1], 5))
b0, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack("I4", blob))
b1, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack("I4", blob, 5))
print("Cmp result", comp_int64s(a0, a1, b0, b1))
```

EDIT: Added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a method that looks like it's working.  It's a little ugly though.

The first step is to compare top 32 bits as 2 compliment #’s
MSB sign bit stays, so numbers keep correct relations

```
-1  —> -1
0 —> 0
9223372036854775807 = 0x7fff ffff ffff ffff -> 0x7ffff ffff = 2147483647
```

So returning the result from the MSB's works unless they are equal, then the LSB's need to get checked.

I have a few cases to establish the some patterns:

```
-1 = 0xffff ffff ffff ffff
-2 = 0xffff ffff ffff fffe
32 bit is:
-1 -> 0xffff ffff = -1
-2 -> 0xffff fffe = -2
-1 > -2 would be like -1 > -2 : GOOD
```

And

```
8589934591 = 0x0000 0001 ffff ffff
8589934590 = 0x0000 0001 ffff fffe
32 bit is:
8589934591 -> ffff ffff = -1
8589934590 -> ffff fffe = -2
8589934591 > 8589934590 would be -1 > -2 : GOOD
```

The sign bit on MSB’s doesn’t matter b/c negative numbers have the same relationship between themselves as positive numbers.  e.g regardless of sign bit, lsb values of `0xff` > `0xfe`, always.

What about if the MSB on the lower 32 bits is different?

```
0xff7f ffff 7fff ffff = -36,028,799,166,447,617
0xff7f ffff ffff ffff = -36,028,797,018,963,969
32 bit is:
-..799.. -> 0x7fff ffff = 2147483647
-..797.. -> 0xffff ffff = -1
-..799.. < -..797.. would be 2147483647 < -1 : BAD!
```

So we need to ignore the sign bit on the lower 32 bits.  And since the relationships are the same for the LSBs regardless of sign, just using
the lowest 32 bits unsigned works for all cases.

This means I want signed for the MSB's and unsigned for the LSBs - so chaging `I4` to `i4` for the LSBs.  Also making big endian official and using '>' on the struct.unpack calls:

```
-- ...
local comp_int64s = function (as0, au1, bs0, bu1)
    if as0 > bs0 then
        return 1
    elseif as0 < bs0 then
        return -1
    else
        -- msb's equal comparing lsbs - these are unsigned
        if au1 > bu1 then
            return 1
        elseif au1 < bu1 then
            return -1
        else
            return 0
        end
    end
end
local l, as0, au1, bs0, bu1
as0, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack(">i4", ARGV[1]))
au1, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack(">I4", ARGV[1], 5))
bs0, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack(">i4", blob))
bu1, l = bit.tobit(struct.unpack(">I4", blob, 5))
print("Cmp result", comp_int64s(as0, au1, bs0, bu1))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Comparing* is a simple string compare `s1 == s2`.

*Greater than* is when **not** `s1 == s2` and `i1 < i2`.

*Less than* is the real work. [string.byte](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.byte) allows to get single bytes as `unsigned char`. In case of unsigned integer, you would just have to check bytes-downwards: `b1==b2` -> check next byte; through all bytes -> **false** (equal); `b1>b2` -> **false** (greater than); `b1<b2` -> **true**. Signed requires more steps: first check the sign bit (uppermost byte >127). If sign 1 is set but not sign 2, integer 1 is negative but not integer 2 -> **true**. The opposite would obviously result in **false**. When both signs are equal, you can do the unsigned processing.

When you can pack more bytes to an integer, it's fine too, but you have to adjust the sign bit check. When you have LuaJIT, you can use the **ffi** library to cast your string into a byte array into an int64.